# Matlab surface plot (with unusual input)

Tags: matlab

I wish to make a 3D plot in matlab using the following data:

```
x = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3];
y = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4];
F = [4,5,6,7,5,6,7,8,6,7,8,9]; % for example
```

where F=F(x,y) in a function of x and y. (Ie F(1,1) = 4, F(1,2) = 5, F(1,3) = 6, reading down each column.)

To give an idea of the plot I would like to make: If I knew the function F(x,y) analytically I would use the following code:

```
xvec = [1,2,3];
yvec = [1,2,3,4];
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xvec, yvec);
Fvalues = F(X,Y); % where F = @(x,y) ... has been defined
surf(X,Y,Fvalues);
```

Comment: So what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a *very* simple trick here. You are getting `4x3` matrices - `X` and `Y`. You just have to arrange `F` in the proper format and then use `surf` command. Write your code as follows:

```
xvec = [1,2,3];
yvec = [1,2,3,4];
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xvec, yvec);

%reshaping F
F=reshape(F,4,3); 

surf(X,Y,F);
```